# What does "cleaning up" mean in MySQL InnoDB transaction status and how to prevent it?

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, performance-tuning

In our database (MySQL 5.6.22 on RDS) we have a lot of transactions (~500) in a state "cleaning up" under the load:

```
> SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS;
...
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
...
---TRANSACTION 70150348714, not started
MySQL thread id 132590, OS thread handle 0x2b2a712ca700, query id 10842420427 <ip> <user> cleaning up
...
```

The only information I have found is:

> The thread has processed one command and is preparing to free memory and reset certain state variables.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/general-thread-states.html

And this question comment mentions:

> You may need to fine tune some memory related parameters if you see this often in your instance.

[Many transactions are getting stuck in the "cleaning up" state - what could cause that?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86255/many-transactions-are-getting-stuck-in-the-cleaning-up-state-what-could-caus)

What could be the actual problem? Why are so many transactions in "cleaning up" state? What memory parameters can I fine tune to prevent it?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the slow queries in the slowlog?

Answer (score 2):

To quote the man himself:

> Hi!
>
> Yes, you can get processes in the 'cleaning up' state if your
>   table_cache is too small.
>
> The general answer is that you should increase your table cache if the
>   status variable 'opened_tables' tend to increase a lot over time.
>
> Yours,
>   Monty

Source: Grokbase.com

Comment: Original thread where this was posted is (I think) http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/10388

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by connection(s) that haven't been closed by the application. I've observed for some open connections `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` reports "cleaning up" but `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` reports the transaction as sleeping.

I've seen open connections with "cleaning up" status in 5.6 and 5.7.

You should check the application is closing all its MySQL connections.